# Why is charge proportional to capacitance?

Tags: capacitance, dielectric

I'm having trouble understanding why the charge is multiplied by the dielectric constant in the following question:

> A parallel-plate capacitor has capacitance C0 = 5.00 pF when there is air between the plates. The separation between the plates is 1.50 mm. A dielectric with K = 2.70 is inserted between the plates of the capacitor, completely filling the volume between the plates. What is the maximum magnitude of charge on each plate if the electric field between the plates is not to exceed 3.00  104 V/m?

Using $E = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_{0}A}$ and $C = \frac{k\epsilon_{0}A}{d}$, I can substitute for $\epsilon_{0}A$ with $\frac{Cd}{k}$. This means that solving for Q gives me $Q = \frac{ECd}{k}$. However, the answer has the charge $Q$ multiplied by the dielectric constant, meaning $k$ is on the top. Why is this the case? Are there certain situations where I can't use $E = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_{0}A}$?

Answer (score 1):

The strength of the electric field is affected by the dielectric.  That means your first equation is not correct.  It should be $E = \frac{Q}{\epsilon A} = \frac{Q}{k \epsilon_0 A}$.

Now when you do that particular substitution, instead of $Q = \frac{ECd}{k}$, you get $Q = ECd$.  The explict $k$ is gone (but the effect of it is still present inside the capacitance value).